# Update select2 contents while it is focused and idle

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I'm using the following code to dynamically load data into a select2 (version 2.5.3) widget.

```
var arr = [];
$.ajax(...); // Load data into the array

hiddenInput.select2({
    data: { results: arr }
});
```

If I'm focused onto the search field of the widget, the new data only shows up if:

1. I click away and then focus again
2. I start typing into the field

Calling `hiddenInput.val()` does nothing, and calling `hiddenInput.change()` or `hiddenInput.trigger('change.select2')` closes the dropdown and gets rid of any entered text.

How do I make it so that the data is updated without requiring the user to do anything, and without resetting the state of the widget (eg. no closing and clearing the search field)?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve? Why do you need to do this? Why is the data changing while the user has focus?

Comment: @Miro I am loading some data using an ajax call. This load may take a second or two--the 'no matches found' text will read 'loading' while this happens. The user has access to the search box before the load completes so that they can start searching as fast as possible. If they click on the search field but don't type anything however, the results box will continue to say 'loading' despite the fact that the data has already been loaded. I want the select2 widget to recognize this and update the display accordingly.

Comment: Yes. I get that. But why do you have to load the data after the user has focused and not before that? That way it wont have to update while the user has focus. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/mirohristov/h2trn161/2/

Comment: @Miro I can't load data that I don't have? I'm making the ajax call as soon as the page loads--*not* after the user has focused the field--but it still takes time.

Comment: I see. Well your best bet, in this case, is to load the data with the initial request (as HTML with <option>).  Otherwise, you can add `disabled` attribute to the select while the ajax is loading. That's what I would do. The reason the text clears is because 'change.select2' rebuilds the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a temporary solution to get the widget to reflect that the data has changed. It's basically just emulating the behaviour of typing something into the search field.

```
var searchField = hiddenInput.data("select2").search;
if (searchField.is(":focus")) {
    var searchTerm = searchField.val();
    hiddenInput.select2("search", "");
    hiddenInput.select2("search", searchTerm);
}
```

This doesn't seem like a very 'clean' work around however so I'll hold off on accepting this as the final solution until a more proper one comes along.